# Call to undefined method AcceptanceTester::getModule

Tags: codeception

Here is my code -

```
<?php
class ClassiDescCest{
        public function desc(AcceptanceTester $I){
            $classifications = $this->getModule('WebDriver')->_findElements('/html/body/div[1]/div/section/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/span/a/span');
            echo $classifications.size();

        }
}
```

Here is the error that I am getting - 
[Error for undefined method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkJDI.png)

Comment: $classifications.size(); looks like Javascript code, PHP way is count($classifications);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->getModule()` can't be used in the Cest file,

`_findElements` is a hidden method and can only be used in helpers as documented in http://codeception.com/docs/06-ModulesAndHelpers

Also check if [grabMultiple](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#grabMultiple) method does what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
grabMulptiple() worked for me.