# Undefined method AcceptanceTester::getModule

Tags: php, yii2, webdriver, phpunit, codeception

i have a Yii2 project and i'm running automated tests with Codeception.

I intend to get a reference to the Webdriver instance.
How to do that?

I am getting an undefined method exception when i call $this->getModule("WebDriver") from the Cest class or the Acceptancetester class.

This is my acceptance.suite.yml file:

```
    class_name: AcceptanceTester
    modules:
        enabled:
            - Cli:
            - WebDriver:
                url: http://localhost:8081/
                browser: firefox
                port: 4455
            - Yii2:
                part: [orm,fixtures]
                entryScript: index-test.php
                cleanup: false
```

And this is my AcceptanceTester that is trying to reference the WebDriver:

```
    /**
     * Inherited Methods
     * @method void wantToTest($text)
     * @method void wantTo($text)
     * @method void execute($callable)
     * @method void expectTo($prediction)
     * @method void expect($prediction)
     * @method void amGoingTo($argumentation)
     * @method void am($role)
     * @method void lookForwardTo($achieveValue)
     * @method void comment($description)
     * @method \Codeception\Lib\Friend haveFriend($name, $actorClass = NULL)
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD)
    */
    class AcceptanceTester extends \Codeception\Actor
    {
        use _generated\AcceptanceTesterActions;


        public function sendEnterKey(){
             // the following line will raise an exception
            $driver = $this->getModule("WebDriver");
            $driver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys(\Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverKeys::ENTER);
        }

    }
```

I am getting an exception saying " Call to undefined method AcceptanceTester::getModule" when calling the AcceptanceTester::sendEnterKey method

p.s.
There is another question with the same title: [Call to undefined method AcceptanceTester::getModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38763010), but this is not a duplicate. 
 The problem in that question was due to the getModule call being in the Cest class. But i did not make the same mistake. I put the call in the AcceptanceTester

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to undefined method AcceptanceTester::getModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38763010/call-to-undefined-method-acceptancetestergetmodule)

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam not a duplicate: the problem in that question was due to the getModule call being in the Cest class. But i did not make the same mistake. I put the call in the AcceptanceTester.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to put the method inside the Acceptance helper class.

It should be located at `/_support/Helper/Acceptance.php`

So try this:

```
<?php
namespace Helper;

// here you can define custom actions
// all public methods declared in helper class will be available in $I

class Acceptance extends \Codeception\Module
{
    public function sendEnterKey()
    {
        $driver = $this->getModule("WebDriver");
        $driver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys(\Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverKeys::ENTER);
    }
}
```